# Lapply over several parameters, faster method

Tags: r, apply, lapply, mapply

Suppose I have two vectors

```
 a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
 b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
```

and a function

```
calc <- function(x,y){x + y)
```

I want to apply this function for the 1st value in `a` for each value in `b`. Suppose in my case `calc` only allows a single value from `a` and `b` as input, so `lapply(a,calc,b)` wouldn't work because the length(b) is not 1 then (gives me an error).

Also `mapply` doesnt give me the wanted solution either, it only applies the function on paired values, i.e. `1+6`, `2+7`, etc.

**So I built a function that gave me the wanted solution**

```
myfunc <- function(z){lapply(a,calc,z)}
```

and applied it on b

```
solution <- lapply(b,myfunc)
```

We see here that the difference to `lapply(a,calc,b)` or a nested `lapply(a,lapply,calc,b)` is that it gives me all the values in its own list. Thats what I wanted or at least it was a function that gave me the right result with no error.

Now, is there a **faster/ more trivial method**, because I just experimented here a little. And with my function which is much larger than `calc` it takes 10 minutes, but maybe I have to slim down my original function and there would not be a faster method here...

**EDIT:**

In my function there is something like this,

```
calc <- function(x,y){
# ...
number <- x
example <- head(number,n=y)
# ...
}
```

where a vector as an input for y doesnt work anymore. With `lapply(a,lapply,calc,b)` or `lapply(a,calc,b)` I get an error,

```
Error in head.default(number, n = y) : length(n) == 1L is not TRUE
```

Comment: Does not return the results in in a list, but maybe you could use `outer(a,b,calc)`?

Comment: @Florian need to be careful with outer, `function` needs to be properly vectorized

Comment: See my comment under @AkselA's response...

Comment: I'm getting confused. We already knew your function only accepted scalar, or single values, as inputs. In a comment you asked about how to access values, what was that about? Does it have anything to do with the linear regressions you mentioned?

Comment: Well, my output from my function is a fit from a linear regression and with my solution I could simply access them, but with your solution which results in a matrix the fits seem to be split up. The solution should have 5x5 fits, thus 25 elements in the matrix but yours has like 300 elements in the matrix...

Comment: I arranged the output in a matrix because I assumed your function returned a scalar. If it doesn't, things might get messy. How does it look if you don't convert to a matrix?

Comment: Well m1 gives me a matrix, how do I not get a matrix with your code?

Comment: What if you set `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` in the `mapply()` call?

Comment: It would really help if your example was closer to your actual problem. Is the function you use really large, is that why you won't post it?

Comment: Actually, `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` solved it, why didnt I think of that, I even had it used earlier. The output is indeed nicer because it is a list with 25 elements where I can look it up horizontally in `eg` to which input parameter the `n`-th element belongs.

Comment: However, its not really faster than my solution in OP. That was my original question, if there's a faster method...

Comment: Seems like you'll have to look at `calc()` then and see if there's a way to make it quicker. Maybe head over to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: Okay, if theres no faster way I might actually do that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jackbauer have you checked my answer below?

Comment: @nadizan yes, but as stated my function doesnt actually sum values, the output is a fit and in my function theres a part `example <- head(number,n=y)` which requires single scalars as input values, so your function might work on the first `calc` function shown but not for my actual function...

Answer (score 1):

As Florian says, `outer()` could be an option.

```
outer(a, b, calc)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    7    8    9   10   11
# [2,]    8    9   10   11   12
# [3,]    9   10   11   12   13
# [4,]   10   11   12   13   14
# [5,]   11   12   13   14   15
```

But as MichaelChirico mentions, with a function that isn't vectorized it won't work. In that case something else has to be hacked together. These might or might not be quicker than your current solution.

All combinations (so both `calc(1, 6)` and `calc(6, 1)` are performed, similar to `outer()`

Number of calculations: n<sup>2</sup>

```
eg <- expand.grid(a, b)

m1 <- mapply(calc, eg[,1], eg[, 2])
matrix(m1, 5)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    7    8    9   10   11
# [2,]    8    9   10   11   12
# [3,]    9   10   11   12   13
# [4,]   10   11   12   13   14
# [5,]   11   12   13   14   15
```

Only unique combinations (so assumes your function is symmetric)

Number of calculations: (n<sup>2</sup> - n) / 2

```
cn <- t(combn(1:length(a), 2))

m2 <- mapply(calc, a[cn[, 1]], b[cn[, 2]])
mat <- matrix(, length(a), length(a))
mat[upper.tri(mat)] <- m2
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA    8    9   10   11
# [2,]   NA   NA   10   11   12
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA   12   13
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   14
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

This second one ignores the diagonal, but adding those values are easy, as that's what the OPs `mapply()` call returned.

```
diag(mat) <- mapply(calc, a, b)
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    7    8    9   10   11
# [2,]   NA    9   10   11   12
# [3,]   NA   NA   11   12   13
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   13   14
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   15
```

Comment: As described `outer()` doesnt work for my function because I need single input values (thats why lapply / nested lapply dont work either). Your second proposition with mapply calculated without error. The resulting values are fits from a linear regression (`fit <- lm(value1~value2)`), how would I access them? (m is a `matrix`)

Comment: With my own functions the output is  a list and I can access them by 
`for (i in 1:length(solution)){
  for (j in 1:length(solution[[i]])){
    print(summary(solution[[i]][[j]]))
    }`

Comment: @jackbauer: It might be better if you add those details to your question. Maybe give an example subset of your actual data? Or you can use a builtin dataset like `mtcars` to explain your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me, adding `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to the `mapply` function, thanks to @AkselA.

```
eg <- expand.grid(a, b)

m1 <- mapply(calc, eg[,1], eg[, 2],SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

However, this method is only slightly faster than my own solution in my OP.